# elements inside the UICollectionViewCell are not getting highlighted/selected

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

[image]

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = Colors.lightGrayDivider
        }
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .white
        }
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = Colors.lightGrayDivider
        }
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUnhighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .white
        }
    }
```

Issue: the contentView of `UICollectionView` is highlighted/selected along with the `UILabel` but the `shadowView(UIView)` doesn't get highlighted/selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the backgrounds of those elements? If they are white they will remain white while the content view changes colour. You will want to make sure they are clear backgrounds so that you can see the content views colour through their own background.